# Puppeteer/Chromium proxy ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: docker, google-chrome, puppeteer

I want to use puppeteer inside docker but got an error with the https version of any websites

My dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.8.0-slim

ENV http_proxy http://10.156.10.155:3128
ENV https_proxy http://10.156.10.155:3128

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y nano vim google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN npm config set proxy http://10.156.10.155:3128
RUN npm config set https-proxy http://10.156.10.155:3128
RUN npm i puppeteer@5.2.1

ADD screenshot.js /app/screenshot.js

RUN groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser
RUN chown -R pptruser:pptruser /app


USER pptruser

WORKDIR /app
# CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

And screenshot.js:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: ['--disable-dev-shm-usage', 
      '--proxy-server=http://10.156.10.155:3128',
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox'

    ]
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.7) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.7');
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})().catch(error => console.trace(error));
```

I have no error for http://example.com, but i have this error for the https version:

```
Trace: Error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED at https://example.com
    at navigate (/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:113:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async FrameManager.navigateFrame (/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:88:21)
    at async Frame.goto (/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:405:16)
    at async Page.goto (/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:826:16)
    at async /app/screenshot.js:19:3
    at /app/screenshot.js:23:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I've tried settings http_proxy and https_proxy env, without any success.

I've just tried without docker, and same thing, so not related to docker :/

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same problem, use option --user-agent in puppeteer.launch:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: ['--disable-dev-shm-usage',
      '--proxy-server=http://10.156.10.155:3128',
      '--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.7) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.7"',
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
    ]
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely matter of your proxy settings, not puppeteer nor docker. Unfortunately, I do not have access to your proxy, thus there's no way I could reproduce it. But first thing which comes to my mind - you usually have to authenticate when using https proxy. You can pass the username and password using `page.authenticate` before doing a navigation:

```
page.authenticate({username:'user', password:'password'});
```

These are usually some domain credentials.

The other thing which comes to my mind are certificate errors, but I see you `ignoreHTTPSErrors` already :)

If authentication does not work, I suggest opening Chrome and checking proxy settings there - maybe you're missing something else?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it's an http proxy, so I don't have to authenticate :)   I've tried to get the page with wget and there was no problem at all :/

Comment: Could you share wget command used? just `wget https://example.com`?

Comment: By the way, maybe such proxy-chain could help: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2801#issuecomment-400182599

Comment: Just a simple `wget https://example.com`, my env var http_proxy and https_proxy set to http://10.156.10.155:3128

Comment: proxy-chain didn't help, same error: `Trace: Error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED at https://example.com`

Comment: Hmm...after taking a look how proxy should be configured: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings#TOC-Command-line-options-for-proxy-settings I believe that your arg should look like this: `'--proxy-server=http=10.156.10.155:3128;https=10.156.10.155:3128'`. I believe that right now it does not use proxy for https requests.

Comment: Unfortunately same error :/. I've tried `--proxy-auto-detect`, same.

Comment: And can you possibly open chromium yourself and try to navigate to https://example.com?

Comment: So something is wrong with https proxy for chromium... You sure it's not matter of credentials? Maybe this plugin could help https://github.com/gajus/puppeteer-proxy but I doubt it... If it does not work when you open chromium, it's not related to puppeteer at all

Comment: Ok, i had a chat with the proxy guys, and that's because the user agent is blocked. So puppeteer (or the plugin i use) can change the user agent for http requests but not for https one

Comment: It was that, I ran chromium with --user-agent="...", and it works ! Thank you for your time Marek !